# Segfault in a threaded C program on Linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, segmentation-fault

I have to code a thread example for my class homework. Somehow I'm getting a Segfault after creating my child-Process via copy() (have to use that sadly).

```
void thread(void);
#define CLONE_VM        0x00000100
#define ANSWER_TRUE     "t"
#define ANSWER_FALSE    "f"

static char stack[2];

int main(void) {
void** childThreadBP = NULL;
void** childThread = NULL;

int pid = 0;

puts("create stack for child process...");
void ** new_stack = (void **) malloc(128);    
//new_stack = (void **) ((char *)new_stack + 128); 

puts("create child process...");    
pid = clone(thread, new_stack, CLONE_VM, NULL);

puts("write PID to shared stack...");
stack[0] = (char) pid;

puts("child answered:");
while(1){}
if (stack[1] == ANSWER_TRUE) {
    puts("PIDs are equal.");
}
else {
    puts("PIDs are NOT equal.");
}
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void thread(void) {
puts("[child]: I'm alive!");
int pidSelf;

pidSelf = getpid();
if (pidSelf == (int)stack[0]) {
    puts("[child]: dad the PID you gave me is correct!");
    stack[1] = ANSWER_TRUE;
}
else {
    puts("[child]: dad the PID you gave me is NOT correct!");
    stack[1] = ANSWER_FALSE;
}
}
```

Maybe you see what my mistake is... - what is wrong with the code format?!

I just need help fixing the seg fault - the rest should be ok (I think ;) )

greetings!!

Comment: Why are you using `clone(2)` instead of the pthreads library?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: because we have to... :/

Comment: @MartinJames: didn't make it better, sadly..

Comment: The code compiles and works for me without segfault but says: `[child]: dad the PID you gave me is NOT correct!`

Comment: You are passing the `clone` system call a pointer to the end of the stack, but it needs a pointer to the beginning.

Comment: @HristoIliev interesting, now it is working too - with the use of more bytes via malloc.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yep you are right - fixed that. now its working even though the output is still wrong...

Comment: Both character literals should be enclosed in single quotes, not in double quotes. The thread function shoud be `int thread(void *)` and not `void thread(void)`. `new_stack` shoud be just `void *` and not `void **`. There is a caching issue with `getpid()` - see the man page of `clone(2)`...

Comment: `clone(2)` takes the end of the stack area, since it grows downwards on x86 and most other systems and just passing a pointer tells it nothing about how big is the area that it points to.

Comment: See the notes section of the `clone(2)` manpage on how to use the actual syscall and bypass the caching (not that it helps - I've tried it with your code with no success)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues. The first is as Martin James stated, you need a larger stack size. I used 16384 and that worked fine. Second, you need to pass in the top of the memory space, your line:

```
new_stack = (void **) ((char *)new_stack + 128);
```

is fine, uncomment it and change it to the larger stack size:

```
void ** new_stack = (void **) malloc(16384);    
new_stack = (void **) ((char *)new_stack + 16384);
```

Thirdly, you have an issue with your PID storage. The stack array must be an integer, as the pid can be larger than a char variable can fit (my PID was 25689).

That should fix it up.